# range function with if-else statment in python

Tags: python-3.x

when I enter
45 200
why I am getting no
and the reason is the if-else statement is coming false
but I don't know why

```
T = int(input("i"))
for _ in range(T):
    X,Y = map (int, input().split(" "))
    if Y in  (X, X+200):
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Answer (score 1):

`if Y in (X,X+200)` will check if `Y` exists in the tuple consisting of the values `X` and `X+200`. You might be looking for the python [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function.

`if Y in range(X,X+200)` should do what you need.

Comment: it is still not working in the problem >  https://www.codechef.com/submit/ADVANCE